# Value of a Tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I was wondering if you could help me clarify what does the author means by value in the following problem:

Find the value $F(v,f)$ of the tensor $F=e^1 \otimes e_2 +e^2  \otimes (e_1+3e_3) \in T^1_1(V)$, where $v=e_1+5e_2+4e_3$ and $f=e^1+e^2+e^3$.

The notations here refers to: $T^1_1(V)=V^* \otimes V$, $\{e_i\}$ are the basis of $V$ and $\{e^i\}$ are the basis of $V^*$. The dimension of $V$ is 3.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, $e^1,e^2,e^3$ are specifically the *dual basis* of $e_1,e_2,e_3$, that is, $e^i:V\to\Bbb R$ linear functions such that $e^i(e_j)=\delta_{i,j}$.

Then we have e.g. $e^2(v)=e^2(e_1+5e_2+4e_3)=5$. 
With these,
 $$\begin{align}w:=F(v) &= e^1(v)\cdot e_2 + e^2(v)\cdot (e_1+3e_3)= \\ &= 
1\cdot e_2 + 5\cdot(e_1+3e_3) \\
F(v,f)=f(F(v)) &= e^1(w)+e^2(w)+e^3(w) = \\
&=5+1+15 = {\bf 21}\,.
\end{align}$$

---

All in all, with the given $F$, you will simply get
$$F(v,f)=e^1(v)\cdot f(e_2) + e^2(v)\cdot f(e_1+3e_3)\,.$$

Comment: That makes much sense, but another question I haves is: How you you know that the  $f$ comes out when evaluating the value of the tensor? By that I mean, is it by definition that $F(v,f)=f(F(v))$?

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with your notation, but that was the only way I could interpret it by the given data.
Nevertheless, the point is that you will get the same, if you evaluate first with $f$, using first
$$F(f)=e^1\cdot f(e_2) + e^2\cdot f(e_1+3e_3)\,.$$